# Uncaught referenceError variable undefined

Tags: javascript

Why the example bellow works on any javascript online tool like "playcode.io", "jsfidle" etc, but it renus 'undefined variable' on any browser when editing with vscode?

I have also tried this on Sublime... same outcome.

```
var myName = "John Doe";
console.log(myName);
```

The result on either chrome or firefox consoles are: Uncaught referenceError myName is undefined. 1:13

There are no syntax errors. Otherwise it would not run on playcode.io , for example.

[here is the error message as displayed both on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlS9W.png)

[...and on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Bak.png)

EDIT:

As pinted by @Quentin , it was supposed to run from inside an html `<script>`

Here is what i did:

```
<html>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <body>
        <script>
             var myName = "John Doe";
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI the code works in my chrome console. I'd assume your issues are due to the `var` keyword because of the scope it creates.

Comment: Share your full function.

Comment: @dan, this has nothing to do with the use of `var`

Comment: @Atul Kumar that small piece of code is all I've got. It's just a test for you guys to see that, no matter if create a new .js file, it keeps complaining about an undefined variable. That's freaking weird.

Comment: share screenshot of same.

Comment: @AtulKumar There you go. I've edited the thread and added both evidences: on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @dan how come it being related to the use of var? It works everywhere else but in my browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type the URL of a JavaScript file into the address bar of a web browser, it will render the JavaScript source code as text.

It will **not** execute the JavaScript.

Consequently, the variable is not declared and does not exist when you try to access it in the browser's developer tools.

The usual way to execute JavaScript in a browser is to create an HTML document which loads it using a `<script>` element, but also see *browser extensions* and *service workers*. Outside of browsers, tools such as Node.js exist to execute JS.

Comment: Just like you said, man. I put the .js syntax inside an .html file and bingo ! Much apreciated !